# Handling from json reaponse function to local variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to give variable from JSON to global variable...

See my jquery code:

```
$.post("php/init.php", function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    });
    alert(data);
    var text = $("#text").val();
});
```

How i can alert the "data" variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign or alert the local variable in its scope.

```
$.post("php/init.php", function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
               alert(data);
       var text = $("#text").val();
    });

});
```

On callback response you can handle it.

Comment: But, I want to insert a variable text in the future using ajax.. How i can do this?

Comment: add this text to hidden variable and you can use whenever you want on this page